# Cómo puedo diferenciar 2 JButton en una matriz de estos por el color que tienen o por algún identificador único?

Tags: java, condiciones, jbutton

estoy creando un programa que replica al juego de Battleship con una matriz de JButton, tengo el problema de que cuando genero los "barcos"(JButtons de otros colores) en posiciones aleatorias(debe ser asi), no se puede superponer un barco a otro, y la única restriccion mediante if que se me ocurre es comparando los colores de ambos JButton(son 4 modelos de "barcos" distintos que quiero crear), pero no sé como hacerlo, he intentado mediante equals, pero no funciona, ya que los detecta iguales a ambos botones, se me ocurrió obtener el codigo RGB para comparar asignando cada código a unas variables, pero no sé como obtener el código RGB, en resumen, estoy perdido y no llego a la solución.

Este es el código para generar al azar dentro de la matriz de JButton:

```
/* 
Forma barco:
    0
000000
    0
*/
int numero = (int)(Math.random()*19);
int numero2 = (int)(Math.random()*8);

if(numero2==0){numero2+=1;}
for (int i=0;i<=5;i++){
    Boton[numero][numero2].setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,0));
    numero+=1;
}
Boton[numero-2][numero2-1].setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,0));
Boton[numero-2][numero2+1].setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,255,0));
```

if que intenté usar:

```
ColorModel color1=Boton[numero][numero2].getColorModel();
ColorModel color2=Boton[0][0].getColorModel();
                
System.out.println("Color 1: "+color1+"\nColor 2: "+color2);
if(color1.equals(color2)){
      System.out.println(":(");
}else{
      System.out.println("Funciona!");
}

/*
Salida: 
Color 1: DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0
Color2: DirectColorModel: rmask=ff0000 gmask=ff00 bmask=ff amask=0
*/
(No sé como pasarlo a RGB)
```

Comment: Yo ocuparía Clases, pero esto tiene pinta de ser una tarea de un curso básico, así que lo que te recomiendo es crear otra matriz de enteros paralela a la de los botones. Entonces ahí guardas números que serían el estado de cada casilla. Por ejemplo 0=Casilla desocupada .- 1=Casilla ocupada.- 2=Casilla ocupada con disparo fallido y 4=casilla ocupada con disparo acertado. Luego tus validaciones de lógica del juego la haces en esa matriz

Comment: Si asignas el color de fondo compara con el color de fondo; puedes usar los colores predefinidos, en este caso: `boton[x][y].getBackground().equals(Color.yellow)`.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios!, Es parte de un curso de introducción a java, la matriz aparte con números enteros paralela a la de los botones, fue la solución que ocupe y me funciona perfectamente, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes diferenciar dos JButton en una matriz utilizando su método setName() para asignarles un nombre único y luego utilizar el método getName() para obtener el nombre de un botón en particular. Por ejemplo, si deseas asignar el nombre "boton1" al primer botón de la matriz y el nombre "boton2" al segundo botón de la matriz, puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

```
JButton[][] matrizBotones = new JButton[2][2];

// Asigna el nombre "boton1" al primer botón de la matriz
matrizBotones[0][0].setName("boton1");

// Asigna el nombre "boton2" al segundo botón de la matriz
matrizBotones[0][1].setName("boton2");
```

Luego, para obtener el nombre de un botón en particular, puedes utilizar el método getName() de la siguiente manera:

```
// Obtiene el nombre del primer botón de la matriz
String nombreBoton1 = matrizBotones[0][0].getName();

// Obtiene el nombre del segundo botón de la matriz
String nombreBoton2 = matrizBotones[0][1].getName();
```

De esta forma, puedes utilizar el nombre de cada botón para diferenciarlos en tu código.

Si deseas diferenciar dos botones